# how to fix that loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I would like to achieve is given an input ( http parameters ) to the tool, send it back to another server but for each http parameter an extra string to the current values

based on @liakoyras help:

```
......
attributes = ["AAA", "BBBB", "CCCC" ]
inp = input("HTTP parameters:") #aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff
pars = inp.split("&")
for par in pars:
    for attribute in attributes: 
        query = f"{par}({attribute}"
        data = {inp.replace(par, query):"extrastring2)"}
        print(data)
        r = requests.post(url, data=data)
        .....
```

this is the ( messy ) current results I get, expect the last 3:

```
{'aa=bb(AAA&cc=dd&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb(AAA&cc=dd&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb(BBBB&cc=dd&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb(BBBB&cc=dd&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb(CCCC&cc=dd&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb(CCCC&cc=dd&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd(AAA&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd(AAA&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd(BBBB&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd(BBBB&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd(CCCC&ee=ff': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd(CCCC&ee=ff=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(AAA': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(AAA=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(BBBB': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(BBBB=extrastring2)

{'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(CCCC': 'extrastring2)'}
#post request: aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(CCCC=extrastring2)
```

the last 3 are the perfect results because are valid parameters for the post requests I need to make

So what I wish to obtain is:

```
aa=bb(AAA=extrastring2)&cc=dd&ee=ff

[..]

aa=bb&cc=dd(AAA=extrastring2)&ee=ff

[..]

aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(AAA=extrastring2)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is the relationship between extrastring1 and 2 and the attributes?

Comment: @liakoyras yes! so, 'attributes' is a list of strings ( the original values I should use ), 'extrastring1' is just a fake value, a momentary value, while 'extrastring2' is a default string which does not change, its always the same!
so I loop over attributes and pars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
attributes = ["AAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"]
# inp = input("HTTP parameters:") #aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff
inp = r"aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff"
pars = inp.split("&")
for par in pars:
    for attribute in attributes:
        query = f"{par}({attribute}: extrastring2)"
        data = inp.replace(par, query)
        print(data)
        # r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

The output from this was:

```
aa=bb(AAA: extrastring2)&cc=dd&ee=ff
aa=bb(BBBB: extrastring2)&cc=dd&ee=ff
aa=bb(CCCC: extrastring2)&cc=dd&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd(AAA: extrastring2)&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd(BBBB: extrastring2)&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd(CCCC: extrastring2)&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(AAA: extrastring2)
aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(BBBB: extrastring2)
aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(CCCC: extrastring2)
```

Comment: I'm feeling so stupid... I thought that I needed to follow the 'data = {inp.replace(par, query):"extrastring2)"}' syntax to make the request.post work, while I could just do data = inp.replace(par, query)..... i'm gonna throw myself out of the window for that ahaha ty!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because it removes the original parameter from the input and then appends the modified one *in the end*.

You simply need to change calling of `replace` to `inp.replace(par, query)` in order to put it in the correct position.

```
input_params = "aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff"
pars = input_params.split('&')

for par in pars:
    query = par + "(extrastring1" + "=extrastring2)"
    print(input_params.replace(par, query))
```

This code outputs the expected

```
aa=bb(extrastring1=extrastring2)&cc=dd&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd(extrastring1=extrastring2)&ee=ff
aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff(extrastring1=extrastring2)
```

Comment: There should be a check mark you can press to mark this as the answer,  don't simply upvote it.

Comment: @jagghy I used print in order to make it easier to myself to show what was wrong. The rest (as far as I understand) can achieved through some string manipulation. Try making your post clearer if you still need help, and maybe provide a dummy example of the attributes list because it seems to affect the results after all.

Comment: @RufusVS , if the answer would be the right one, i would have done that. I will do it as soon we figured out how to fix that loop, the upvote is my basic response for helping me

Comment: @liakoyras question updated!(: still many thanks for your kind help!
I don't why my last comment got deleted..